# Trying to create a div and center it, dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called:

```
showModal(data);
```

which when called, will create a modal with the content passed in.  I was trying to center it, but i dont think 'this' is referring to the right object.

```
function showModal(data){
    $("<div class = 'modal'>").css({
        "z-index": Number($("#overlay1").css("z-index")) + 5,
        top: $(window).height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2,
        left: $(window).width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2
    }).append(data).appendTo("body").fadeIn();
}
```

It will just keep it at 0,0 on screen.  How do i adjust it?

Comment: windows width/height changes.

Comment: You should put `"px"` behind the values for `top` and `left`. See if it works: `top: ($(window).height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2) + "px"`

Comment: Ah, vertical centering. I see now.

Comment: what do you expect `this` to refer to? with what you have given us, it refers to the window.

Comment: There are many issues as stake here, the content might not be added yet so there is no height, the `this` context in unknown, the `position` property might not be set, etc... You probably should do a fiddle with some more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function showModal(data){
    var modal = $("<div class = 'modal'>");
    modal.css({
        "z-index": Number($("#overlay1").css("z-index")) + 5,
        top: $(window).height() / 2 - modal.height() / 2,
        left: $(window).width() / 2 - modal.width() / 2
    }).append(data).appendTo("body").fadeIn();
}
```

In your context, `this` refers to the function `showModal` I think. But you're trying to refer to the newly created div with the class "modal". You need to store a reference to it because the `.css` call doesn't change the reference to `this` inside of it. You're probably thinking of normal event bindings, where the anonymous function you pass to it has a new context that jQuery defines `this` as the element in question. With `css`, you aren't providing a callback, and therefore there is no way for jQuery to change or set `this` since there is no new scope/context. I'm probably using the wrong terms (context, scope, etc.)...

**UPDATE**:

The problem **also** seemed to be that since the `data` was not appended before the `.css` call, the modal would not have any substantial width/height. Not sure if the modal being appended to the body needs to be done before the `.css` call or not, but that might help too.

```
function showModal(data) {
    var modal = $("<div class='modal'>");
    modal.appendTo("body")
        .append(data)
        .css({
            "z-index": +$("#overlay1").css("z-index") + 5,
            top: $(window).height() / 2 - modal.height() / 2,
            left: $(window).width() / 2 - modal.width() / 2
        })
        .fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: modal.width and modal.height() are not working.  I was looking at the created modal, and it seems to be at the coordinates winodw.height() && window.width()

Comment: reasoning is that data isnt placed into it though.  There for height and width are 0.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Well, there's a few more things I forgot to make sure of. Let me try some things and then I'll update

Comment: `'px'` isn't necessary for top or left. If you include no unit, jQuery assumes pixels.

Comment: Thats what i was assuming and it was working like that for all of my other things, just seems to have issues properly centering

Comment: @Shmiddty I think I knew that, I don't know why I said it

Comment: @Fallenreaper Sorry, didn't mean to add/update when you were editing. I'll keep the original so people can see our logic and I'll add an explanation for why the second snippet is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The position property of your modal should be absolute.

Comment: Well yes, It is trying to get fixed.

Comment: @SzymonWygnański I agree with you, just test to see fixed or absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `position` as well. Another issue might be that the content is not added yet, so there is no height.

I would also add the modal div onload, move it out of the viewport and then just position it correctly when you run `showModal`, otherwise you will be adding new DIVs every time.

Another issue with your code will be that the modal will not stay centered when resizing the window, but you can fix that with CSS using `50%` margins.

An alternative solution would be a combination of CSS and javascript:

```
var $modal = $("<div class='modal'>").css('left',-10000).appendTo('body'),
    zIndex;

function showModal(data){
    zIndex = parseInt($("#overlay1").css("z-index"), 10)+5;
    $modal.append(data).css({
        left: $modal.width()/-2,
        top: $modal.height()/-2,
        zIndex: zIndex,
        opacity: 0
    }).animate({ opacity: 1 });
}

function hideModal() {
    $modal.css('left',-10000);
}
```

And the CSS:

```
.modal{ position: fixed; margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 50% }
```

This way, the modal is positioned to the far left initially, so you can still calculate the width/height before showing it.